# I have a Java 17 crpytography issue on linux, claims mode is unsupported when java documentation says it is

Tags: java

seems I have come across a rather odd situation.

Setup:
Fedora Linux 36
Java 17 (jdk/jre combo pack through the package manager)
Maven 17

I am attempting to use a minecraft world downloading tool, but the crypto that I am reasonably sure should be supported in Java 17, appears to be non-functional. I was hoping to get some pointers as to where to look.

In short I believe "AES/CFB8/NoPadding" is a valid encryption mode, but my setup seems to disagree.

I have the error I am getting in this code block:

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting AES/CFB8/NoPadding
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:571)
    at proxy.EncryptionManager.lambda$enableEncryption$15(EncryptionManager.java:366)
    at proxy.EncryptionManager.attempt(EncryptionManager.java:109)
    at proxy.EncryptionManager.enableEncryption(EncryptionManager.java:363)
    at proxy.EncryptionManager.lambda$sendReplacementEncryptionConfirmation$13(EncryptionManager.java:333)
    at proxy.EncryptionManager.attempt(EncryptionManager.java:109)
    at proxy.EncryptionManager.sendReplacementEncryptionConfirmation(EncryptionManager.java:314)
    at proxy.EncryptionManager.lambda$setClientEncryptionConfirmation$5(EncryptionManager.java:222)
    at proxy.EncryptionManager.attempt(EncryptionManager.java:109)
    at proxy.EncryptionManager.setClientEncryptionConfirmation(EncryptionManager.java:211)
    at packets.handler.ServerBoundLoginPacketHandler.lambda$new$1(ServerBoundLoginPacketHandler.java:50)
    at packets.handler.PacketHandler.handle(PacketHandler.java:57)
    at packets.DataReader.readPackets(DataReader.java:163)
    at packets.DataReader.pushData(DataReader.java:118)
    at proxy.ProxyServer.lambda$run$4(ProxyServer.java:86)
    at util.ExceptionHandling.attempt(ExceptionHandling.java:12)
    at proxy.ProxyServer.lambda$run$6(ProxyServer.java:83)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Unsupported mode CFB8
    at jdk.crypto.cryptoki/sun.security.pkcs11.P11Cipher.engineSetMode(P11Cipher.java:223)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher$Transform.setModePadding(Cipher.java:385)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:564)
    ... 17 more
Encryption failure! Terminating.
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out FIPS mode was the issue, the encryption method here is apparently disabled while FIPS mode is active, and therefore cannot start, which caused the crash.

So the solution here was to turn off FIPS mode, or use a different encryption method that is supported under FIPS. Since I couldn't change what encryption was being used, as that would introduce other problems, I had to disable FIPS on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Phil thank you so much! We were struggling with this for so long
We had:

```
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Unsupported mode CTS
```

Then I noticed in the log:

```
properties: com.redhat.fips unset, using default value of true
properties: FIPS mode detected
```

I set:

```
-Dcom.redhat.fips=false
```

and it worked!

Comment: The other answer to this question diagnoses the FIPS-crypto problem, but doesn't give a specific solution to it.  Setting the Java property to disable FIPS mode is an important detail.